# Website not showing my updated pages

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, cache

The site is running on Ubuntu 16 with Nginx web server. Recently I have uploaded the new code but when I load the website still it's showing the old pages, I have removed all the files from the document root and uploaded the sample PHP file its worked. So this time I took a pull directly from the Git but, the website is not loading with the new code.

I do not configure any cache headers / CDN for the site. In the doc root, I check the files its fresh code but the site is loading the old one. I have no idea from where it is loading.

curl -I output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2019 10:45:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1j921kls7adn7apspo0c8gdngt; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
```

Nginx conf file

```
 server {

    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site.in;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site.in www.site.in;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/site_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site_error.log;


    location / {
try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;


    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

I never faced this type of issue. Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the correct page/server/site? Access and error logs show nothing unusual? Restarted nginx? Restarted PHP-fpm? PHP caching is most likely the issue here.

Comment: @LennieyYes am accessing the correct server and the site. I could not find any info in error log, its normal. Already I restarted the Nginx, and CSS & JS files are reflecting in the site only PHP files are loading with the old code which is not present in the document root. I have no idea from where it taking that files! Now I have restarted the php `service php7.1-fpm restart` but still the old site is showing up.

Comment: Can you restart the OS? Just to almost safely rule out some caching on it. You are **sure** that no caching on nginx or PHP is enabled? Can you check with `nginx -T`?

Comment: @Lenniey I have disabled the cache adding this opcache.enable=0 in `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini. In nginx I did not mention the cache control or expire headers. Please suggest if any files are there to disable the cache in php config?

Comment: @Lenniey Also I can see these options under Zend Opcache in phpinfo page.                                      
`Opcode Caching Disabled`
`Optimization Disabled`
`SHM Cache Enabled`
`File Cache Disabled`

Comment: @LennieyEven I have rebooted the server now, still its showing the old web page. Its strange.